# Where i upload APNS/p12 cert file in Firebase Console?

Tags: ios, firebase

Hello I have an application in iOS.
That application contain many targets based on different plist info
in past application on GCM messaging that time I have 3 targets
and now I move to the `firebase` so I migrate project to `firebase from GCM console`,
 Now I have 2 new client and I add 2 new target on my project(with firebase),
So I create new `APNS certificates` and its `.p12` but when request for GoogleService-Info.plist file from firebase its simply gives me not ask for .p12 file now I integrate all things in my project but don't get push notification in background

[image: thas same thing missing in Firebase]
got below log :

[image: Thats log screenshot of while application in development]

> I don't found option to upload APNS/.p12 file on firebase Or and is no
>   need then why I don't get notification in background

Answer (score 3, accepted):

don't worry
i have solution

just follow some step

1>> login your account in [https://console.firebase.google.com]

2>>[click on setting icon display in this image][1]

3>> click on  project setting then open 1 tab look below

4>> now load all yours IOS and ANDROID project

5>> just select your IOS project and there 2 option are available for upload file

Comment: Does gcm or fcm have a public api for uploading APNs certificates? I need to do this automatically instead of manually.

Answer (score 8):

The new one is here (2017):

Project Settings and click the "cloud messaging" tab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Images are not available (anymore?)