# How to upload APN Certification to firebase for FCM

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, notifications

Now I'm trying to get FCM in IOS

So I use firebase doc

1. Mac - keychain ; get .certisigningRequest file
2. apple developer console ; generating .cer file using 1. file
3. apple developer console ; generating 'APP ID' using bundle id.
   ex) com.google.PushTest
4. Mac - keychain ; generating .p12 file
5. firebase console ; adding IOS app and set Firebase SDK

---

6. firebase console ; upload APN certi( from num 4. )

---

My problem is num 6!!

I can't upload APN when I try to upload firebase give to like this error

"There was an error reading the certificate."

What should I do??

Please help me thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where i upload APNS/p12 cert file in Firebase Consol?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37583810/where-i-upload-apns-p12-cert-file-in-firebase-consol)

Comment: @AkashSinghSisodia thx for comment but that is not my problem...
my problem is when i upload .p12 certificated file firebase console give me a error like 'there was an error reading the certificate'

Answer (score 1):

i solve my problem my self!!

when i extract .p12 file i chose 2types so firebase console can not accept...

now my pushTest app is work!

thx